# Number of Queries to determine Order of Integers

Tags: problem-solving, sorting

I have this question as follows:

> The eight numbers $11,...,18$ are in a database in some order. You can query any subset of indices, but the reply will be randomly shuffled.
>
> For example, if the order was $17, 12, 13, 16, 11, 15, 14, 18$ and you queried indices $1, 2, 4$, the reply could be $16,17,12$.
>
> What is the minimum number of queries you must make to determine the order of the eight numbers?

I have come up with an empirical answer of $7$ but I have been unable to prove it to myself, hence the question. Many thanks.

Comment: I can do it in 6 queries : ask for (1,2) and (2,3) the number which appears in both request is a the indice 2. The number appearing only in the first request is the first, the number appearing only in the second one is the third. Repeat for (4,5)(5,6) and query (7) and (8)

Comment: I can do it in 5, asking for (1,2,3), (2,3,4), (3,5,6), (6,7,8), (8)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in $3 =\log_2 8$ queries, and this is minimal. For example with the queries:

- 1st: 1,2,3,4
- 2nd: 1,2,5,6
- 3rd: 1,3,5,7

This corresponds to figuring out the binary expansion of the indices of all entries. The 1st entry finds the numbers whose indices have $0$ as first digit, the 2nd finds the numbers whose indices have $0$ as second digit and the 3rd finds the numbers whose indices have $0$ on the third digit.

Comment: Wow, that's brilliant. Thanks a lot!